# RFC 5321 requires my SMTP server with the Enhanced-Status-Codes service extension to reply with “250 OK”

Tags: smtp, rfc

#### [RFC 2034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2034)

```
4.  The Enhanced-Status-Codes service extension

   Servers supporting the Enhanced-Status-Codes extension must preface
   the text part of almost all response lines with a status code. As in
   RFC 1893, the syntax of these status codes is given by the ABNF:

        status-code ::= class "." subject "." detail
        class       ::= "2" / "4" / "5"
        subject     ::= 1*3digit
        detail      ::= 1*3digit

   These codes must appear in all 2xx, 4xx, and 5xx response lines other
   than initial greeting and any response to HELO or EHLO. Note that 3xx
   responses are NOT included in this list.
```

```
221 2.0.0 Goodbye
```

---

#### [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321)

```
4.1.1.9.  NOOP (NOOP)

   This command does not affect any parameters or previously entered
   commands.  It specifies no action other than that the receiver send a
   "250 OK" reply.
```

```
4.1.1.10.  QUIT (QUIT)

   This command specifies that the receiver MUST send a "221 OK" reply,
   and then close the transmission channel.
```

---

I’m running an SMTP server supporting [RFC 2034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2034), but it seems [RFC 2034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2034) and [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) conflict and I don’t know what I should do for my server.

[RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) says the server **`MUST`** reply with “`250 OK`” for the `QUIT` command, but per [RFC 2034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2034), it also **`must`** `preface the text part of almost all response lines with a status code.` Should I give the extension priority (“`250 2.0.0 OK`”)? Wouldn’t it violate [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: The server must not reply with `250 OK` but with `221 OK` to a `QUIT` command.

But I think you misunderstood what the `OK` stands for here, the SMTP standard (without extensions) doesn't care about what comes after the status code, it was a dumb standard and during its implementation every mail server was an open relay. You can reply with `221 Have a nice day` and it's still compliant with RFC 5321.
Also, RFC 5321 does replace and incorporate a lot of the older stuff (see the descriptions).

The important part for you is this:

> This document is a specification of the basic protocol for Internet
> electronic mail transport.  It consolidates, updates, and clarifies
> several previous documents, making all or parts of most of them
> obsolete.  It covers the SMTP extension mechanisms and best practices
> for the contemporary Internet, **but does not provide details about**
> **particular extensions**.

In your example, as far as RFC 5321 is concerned, `221` is the status code and everything beyond that is just text. I think it becomes more clear if you read the termination section of RFC5321:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-3.8

So TL;DR: `221 2.0.0 Goodbye` is perfectly valid for RFC 5321.

Keep in mind, that "extensions" are called that for a reason, they are built on top of the base standard. Rather than replacing, they provide an addition to it.

But don't sweat it, SMTP (and email in general) is a Frankenstein monster, the only reason it wasn't replaced entirely is the wide usage. Providing this kind of backward compatibility for a standard that is in essence over 30 years old is just ridiculous in the 21st century.

And to give you even more peace of mind:

> **2.2.3.  Special Issues with Extensions**
>
> Extensions that change fairly basic properties of SMTP operation are  permitted. The text in other sections of this document must be understood in that context. In particular, extensions can change the minimum limits specified in Section 4.5.3, can change the ASCII character set requirement as mentioned above, or can introduce some optional modes of message handling.
>
> In particular, if an extension implies that the delivery path normally supports special features of that extension, and an intermediate SMTP system finds a next hop that does not support the required extension, it MAY choose, based on the specific extension and circumstances, to requeue the message and try later and/or try an alternate MX host.  If this strategy is employed, the timeout to fall back to an unextended format (if one is available) SHOULD be less than the normal timeout for bouncing as undeliverable (e.g., if normal timeout is three days, the requeue timeout before attempting to transmit the mail without the extension might be one day).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.2.3

Comment: Great answer, thanks! *SMTP (and email in general) is a Frankenstein monster* - I couldn't agree more!

Comment: So the `MUST` was for the status code, not the exact string. Thank you for clarifying.